# Различные ошибки при ответе json с парсинге и csv таблицей

Tags: python, excel, кодировка, csv

После сохранения данных в таблицу файла csv таблицу с помощью Python когда я открываю этот файл Excel у меня меняется кодировка данных таблицы.
Во время создания, записи, сохранения файла. Выставлена кодировка utf-8.
Причина в том что Excel выставляет свою кодировку при открытии файла, как её изменить не знаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Когда мы используем utf-8, эксель любит, чтобы в начале csv-файла был [BOM (byte order mark)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Добавьте его в начало вашего csv-файла и эксель будет открывать его с нужной кодировкой.

Минимальный пример:

```
with open('target_file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\ufeff') # наш BOM
    f.write('наши,данные,нуитд')
```